# (Rails) How do I reference resources from non-restful views...?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, resources, reference, path

How do you ensure that your javascript includes get included properly for all files everywhere using a particular layout?  Basically I have some non-restful actions that I've added.  I haven't added any ROUTES for them, however, using normal text rendering works fine.  It's when I start requiring different "swf" and "js" files (files which are properly placed in PUBLIC) that things get hairy.  I start receiving  "406 Not Acceptable" errors telling me that it's looking for the files in a subdirectory of the current controller.

As it stands I'm in including the JS in "application" layout file.  It works for the INDEX action, but doesn't seem to work for any of the non-restful actions.

Thoughts?

Comment: How can you view any actions you don't have any routes for?! I quote: "I haven't added any ROUTES for them".

Comment: I'm saying I haven't manually edited the ROUTES file for any specific type of activity.  Whatever is there by default is all there is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `javascript_include_tag` ?